# how to delete all the history from back stack except the current page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

I have overridden this method:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    IAsyncResult guide = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(
        "Alert", "Do you want to go to the Menu Page?",
        new string[] { "YES", "NO" }, 0,
        MessageBoxIcon.Alert, null, null);
    int result = (int)Guide.EndShowMessageBox(guide);
    if (result == 0) // YES 
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MenuPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    else // NO 
    {
    }
}
```

Now when I press "no" it still brings me back to the previous page, I just want to override this feature by making it stay on the current page only, without restarting the page. Can I?

Comment: What you are doing in the Yes path of your code, may not work very well. By navigating to MenuPage you are probably creating a bad navigation path in the navigation stack. Try calling NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry (7.1 only) or NavigationService.GoBack() a few times first. Take a look at this video on Channel 9 for an explanation: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Mango-Jump-Start/Mango-Jump-Start-03-Silverlight-on-Windows-PhoneAdvanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'cancel' the event as follows:

```
 e.Cancel = true;
```